# Google Place Autocomplete: Only allow addresses suggested by autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, autocomplete, google-places-api

I have an input field where a user can enter an address. I'm using [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) to suggest addresses to the user. Location is a required field.

What I want is to ensure that a user can only enter an address suggested by Place Autocomplete. So for example, they can't submit the form with "asagasagaaa" as a location.

EJS FILE:

```
<input name="location" type="text" id="location">
```

JS FILE:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ... 
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($('#location')[0]);
    addLocationChangeListener(autocomplete);
   ...
   $("form").submit(function(e){
        doValidations(e, autocomplete);
    });

});
```

addLocationChangeListener:

```
// When user changes location, update map coordinates
function addLocationChangeListener(autocomplete) {
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
        console.log("PLACE CHANGED");
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        console.log("PLACE: ", place);
        console.log("---------------------");
        if(place && place.geometry) {
            ... // save stuff
        }
        ...
    }); // End Add Listener
}
```

The problem I'm having is that it seems like $("#location).val() and autocomplete.getPlace() are not in sync - i.e, they don't always have the same value.

Thus, this doens't work

```
$("#location").on("blur", function() {
      if(autocomplete.getPlace() === undefined) {
          //display error, prevent form submission 
     }
});
```

For example, say you enter the following sequence:

**aaa (invalid location)**

No place changed event will be triggered. Place is undefined, and $("#location") is "aaa". This is fine.

**19 Fairview ave (assume this is a location google suggests)**

$("#location").val() is 19 Fairview ave. Place is 19 Fairview ave. All is good now.

**aaa (invalid location) -- The problem is here**

$("#location").val() is aaa. Place is 19 Fairview ave. PROBLEM!

See the mismatch? Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out. I used setTimeout, so it is kind of a hack and I don't like it. If you have a better solution let me know.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#location").on("blur", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var locVal = $("#location").val(); 
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if(!place) {
            var errMsg = locVal + " is not a valid location. Please select location from list.";
            displayError($("#location"), errMsg);
        } else if(place.formatted_address === locVal) {
            console.log("MATCH");
        } else {
            var errMsg = locVal + " is not a valid location. Please select location from list.";
            displayError($("#location"), errMsg);
        }
    },200);
  });
}

// When user changes location, update map coordinates
function addLocationChangeListener(autocomplete) {
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if(place && place.geometry) {
            $("#location").val(place.formatted_address); // THis is key
        }
       ...
    }); // End Add Listener
}
```

Comment: The root of the issue is that place_changed event is triggered after blur event